# time + sftp commands script: how to correctly redirect output to log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sftp

I built a script to automatize a daily ftp download process. To make it simpler, something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
time sshpass -p "mypass" sftp myuser@sftp.domain.com:/myremotepath/myfile.txt.gz /mylocalpath/myfile.txt.gz 
time sshpass -p "mypass" sftp myuser@sftp.domain.com:/myremotepath/myfile2.txt.gz /mylocalpath/myfile2.txt.gz
```

I execute the script like the following to redirect the output lines to a log file:

```
./sftp_test.sh  > /mylogpath/sftp_test.log 2>1&
```

But it is not working as expected. Just lines like "Fetching /myremotepath/myfile2.txt.gz to /mylocalpath/myfile2.txt.gz" are saved. Not the time command output. Not the others sftp lines.

I would like to save the output exactly as I see it if I execute the script manually without the "  > /mylogpath/sftp_test.log 2>1&" part.

I also tried with the tee command without success.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script may be an option here and so:

```
script -c ./sftp_test.sh /mylogpath/sftp_test.log
```

The -c flag signifies to run a command in a non-interactive environment.